# Connecting ios app to a rails app that uses pow and devise

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to make an ios app that can create/login users and is linked to a Rails api that uses devise. I've tried using Restkit and AFNetworking but am having some trouble. I understand fetch and pull requests but am not sure how to use tokens to create/login users.

I have a rails api that uses pow built from this tutorial:
http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book

Does anybody have any advice/examples that can get me going in the right direction?